# using a proxy when playing a stream with QMediaPlayer in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5, qmediaplayer

I want to play a webradio stream im QT5 with QMediaPlayer behind a proxy server.

I've tryed to use the solution from:

[How to make a proxy working with QMediaPlayer in Qt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322132/how-to-make-a-proxy-working-with-qmediaplayer-in-qt5)

but QNetworkReply isn't derivated from QIODevice, therefore it won't compile.

I've read the documentation, searched a lot but didn't found a solution.

edit: add a minimal reproducible example :

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkProxy proxy;
manager->setProxy(proxy);

QNetworkReply *reply = manager -> get(QNetworkRequest( QUrl()));
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), reply);
```

the compiler says:

> no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘QNetworkReply*’ to
>   ‘QIODevice*’

edit:

In the QT sources of QNetworkReply I've found:

```
class QNetworkReplyPrivate; 
class Q_NETWORK_EXPORT QNetworkReply: public QIODevice
```

but why isn't the upcast to QIODevice working? If i try to make the cast the compiler says:

> error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘reply’ (of type ‘class QNetworkReply*’) to
>   type ‘class QIODevice*’ (source is a pointer to incomplete type)

Comment: QNetworkReply does inherit from QIODevice.

Comment: The compiler says "  no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘QNetworkReply*’ to ‘QIODevice*’" and refer to :   void setMedia(const QMediaContent &media, QIODevice *stream = Q_NULLPTR);

Comment: sorry, it really looks horrible as a comment. I've editet my question, bye.

Comment: Have you included QNetworkReply: `#include <QNetworkReply>`?

Comment: Thanks  eyllanesc, that is the solution for my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the help!

I've "only" forgotten to include QNetworkReply. With this includes it works for me

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkProxy>
#include <QNetworkReply>
```

Hours of troubleshooting and the solution was so simple :)